# Find the distirbution of $U/V$ when both $U, V \sim N(0,1)$ and they are independent

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

**If we have 2 independent random variables$$U, V \sim N(0,1)$$ then what is the distirbution of $U/V$ ?**

My effort so far (maybe there is an easier way):
$$F_{U/V}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{tv}f_{u,v}(u,v)dudv=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_v(v)\int_{-\infty}^{tv}f_u(u)dudv=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-v^2/2} \int_{-\infty}^{tv}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-u^2/2}du \Big)dv$$
Now I am not sure how to continue .
(I did some computations and reached that it is 0 )

Comment: See the third bullet in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Related_distributions) entry about the Cauchy distribution.

Comment: See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2751912/144421).